# Importing sql file from phpmyadmin create error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have successfully backup sql database. But whenever trying to import it shows some error. Like below:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'STORED,
  `purchase_gst` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_due` decimal(10,2' at line 8
```

Here is my code extracted from SQL file:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `purchase`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `purchase` (
  `purchase_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `purchase_date` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `purchase_item` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `purchase_rate` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `purchase_qty` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_from` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `purchase_gross` decimal(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`purchase_qty` * `purchase_rate`)) STORED,
  `purchase_gst` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_due` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_tcost` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_net` decimal(10,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (round(((`purchase_gross` + `purchase_gst`) + `purchase_tcost`),0)) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`purchase_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=372 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: Are you using a  NDB storage engine

Comment: This looks like a dump from MySQL database. The create for virtual felds is different to MariaDB

Comment: Yes this is dump from mysql database

Comment: Change the create table statements in the dumfile to Mariadb syntax. Then it will be works

Comment: If I remove GENERATED ALWAYS column then it is working fine. I tried manually by removing both virtual columns and it is working fine. But the problem is for that virtual column

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of MySQl .This will work on MySQl 5.7 and above versions.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on your mySql version. 
This sql syntax error shows below the MySQL 5.7 version.
Please Check this with in MySQL 5.7 version it's working with below code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `purchase`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `purchase` (
`purchase_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`purchase_date` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`purchase_item` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`purchase_rate` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`purchase_qty` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`purchase_from` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`purchase_gross` decimal(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`purchase_qty` * `purchase_rate`) STORED,
`purchase_gst` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`purchase_due` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`purchase_tcost` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`purchase_net` decimal(10,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (round(((`purchase_gross` + 
`purchase_gst`) + `purchase_tcost`),0)) STORED,
 PRIMARY KEY (`purchase_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;`enter code here`
```